# preserving local user settings folder name

Tags: windows

I have a question regarding the way settings are stored in the user"s local data folder in Windows.
I have a desktop app which uses `ConfigurationLevel.RoamingAndLocal` level for storing settings.
The problem is that the local folder name seems to change after each build/rebuild for some reason. This can be overcome by signing the assembly but this option should be avoided in this case.
So there are two questions here:
1)How can this name be set to be constant?
2) If it's not possible other than by using snk how can the new name be retrieved/known before saving the settings?